# Azure Search API C# Fuzzy / Misspellings Not Working As Expected

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have an index set up with about 1000 items in it. I am doing the following API call to get the results back.

```
        var parameters = new SearchParameters
        {
            Select = new[] { "pageTitle", "pageUrl", "metaDescription" },
            Top = 5,
            QueryType = QueryType.Full
        };
        var results = indexer.Documents.Search<IndexPageData>("childrens bed frames~", parameters);
```

It's working as expected from a getting data back point of view. But if I misspell 'Childrens' with something like 'Childrns' or 'Chidrens'... Was I under the impression the fuzzy/mis-spellings search would understand and return the same results or very similar?

But I get completely different results and they are very poorly matched compared to the correctly spelled term.

Am I missing something with the API?

Comment: I think it's probably a grammar issue (key word here being single): To do a fuzzy search, use the tilde "~" symbol at the end of a single word with an optional parameter, a number between 0 and 2 (default), that specifies the edit distance. For example, "blue~" or "blue~1" would return "blue", "blues", and "glue".
Fuzzy search can only be applied to terms, not phrases. Fuzzy searches can expand a term up to the maximum of 50 terms that meet the distance criteria.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search

Comment: I am using the tilde with the default value, which is 2? But misspellings tend to be mixed up letters or .. ie .. ei or missing letters... I was under the impression Azure search handled things like this?

Comment: Search only "chldren~" ... it should work.  You have 3 words in your string.

Comment: Or, try "childrn~ bed~ frames~" maybe...  It's definitely grammar.  I'm not at my desk, but you should be able to search for an example.

Comment: Thanks. That now works as expected!

Comment: Do you mind if I create an answer based on comments?

Comment: Please do, it's a good answer.

Comment: Of course. I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: thanks for your questions. had tough times investigating why fuzzy search doesn't work at all for me, even with tildas. Found out that fuzzy search requires QueryType = QueryType.Full in parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment from Aaron. I was missing the tilda at the end of each word

childrens~ bed~ frames~

This is now catching things like "childrn bed frames" etc...

Answer (score 0):

"Fuzzy" Search is currently only available for the suggester, [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggestions). You will have to rely on your [language analyser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/language-support) to properly tokenize the word and provide you with the expected result.

Comment: This is incorrect, it is supported in Azure. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_fuzzy

Comment: It's not entirely incorrect, actually. You can't use fuzzy search using azure search sdk without messing with ~ tildas. For suggestions you can use SuggestParameters with option UseFuzzyMatching. SuggestParameters doesn't have such parameter.